# Как назначить StreamSource в BitmapImage в codebehind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, flowdocument

Есть **zip** файл, в котором хранится **FlowDocument** (*Card.xaml*) и папка с изображениями (**Media**). Картинки в **FlowDocument** имеют **Tag**, в котором хранят свой путь относительно **FlowDocument**. Для поиска изображений (**FindImages** метод): [Поиск изображений в FlowDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899852/finding-all-images-in-a-flowdocument)

Как я открываю этот **zip** в **RichTextBox**:

```
string nameOfXamlCardDefault = "Card.xaml";
private void Open_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            //Открываем zip файл
            using (FileStream fullCardZipFile = File.Open(dlg.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                //Смотрим zip c ZipArchive
                using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(fullCardZipFile, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
                {                        
                    //Получаем entry для нашего xaml (FlowDocument)
                    ZipArchiveEntry xamlFileEntry = archive.GetEntry(nameOfXamlCardDefault);
                    //Открываем xaml
                    using (Stream xamlFileStreamInZip = xamlFileEntry.Open())
                    {                            
                        //Загружаем FlowDocument в rtbEditor.Document
                        rtbEditor.Document = XamlReader.Load(xamlFileStreamInZip) as FlowDocument;
                        //Ищем картинки
                        List<Image> images = FindImages(rtbEditor.Document).ToList();
                        foreach (var image in images)
                        {
                            var imageFileEntry = archive.GetEntry(image.Tag.ToString());                                
                            var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                            using (Stream imageFileStream = imageFileEntry.Open())
                            {
                                var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();                                    
                                imageFileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);                                                                        
                                bitmap.BeginInit();
                                bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                                bitmap.StreamSource = memoryStream;
                                bitmap.EndInit();
                                image.Source = bitmap;
                            }
                        }                           
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return;
    }
```

Все изображения в RichTextBox отображаются, только в **BitmapImage** нет **StreamSource**. И потом это приведет к ошибке.

```
<FlowDocument xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" NumberSubstitution.CultureSource="User" AllowDrop="True" PagePadding="5,0,5,0">    
<Paragraph>       
    <Image Tag="Media/image0.png">            
        <Image.Source>
            <BitmapImage CacheOption="OnLoad" BaseUri="{x:Null}"/>
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>        
    <Image Tag="Media/image1.png">            
        <Image.Source>
            <BitmapImage CacheOption="OnLoad" BaseUri="{x:Null}"/>
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>              
</Paragraph>
```

Но, если например просто копировать изображение и вставлять в **RichTextBox**, то это выглядит так и с таким работать можно:

```
  <Image Height="400" Width="600">
       <Image.Source>
           <BitmapImage CacheOption="OnLoad" UriSource="./Image1.bmp" 
            BaseUri="pack://payload:,,wpf1,/Xaml/Document.xaml"/>
       </Image.Source> 
   </Image>
```

Возможно ли как-то изображения из **zip** приводить к такому виду (как при обычном копировании)? Я пытался работать с **MemoryStream**, делать **Freeze()**. Также пытался изображения в **Clipboard** совать и потом их вставлять. Но ни к чему полезному не привело.